# Closing intent selection dialog (after user selection)

Tags: android, android-intent

I use an Navigation intent in my app like:

```
    uri= String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%f,%f",latitude, longitude);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    EventMapOfflineActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Works perfectly, the user can select the app (s)he wants to start.

> But, after the selection the dialog won't close itself and after returning to the app sometimes the user has to press the back button up to 4x to close that dialog.
>
> So is there any way to get the Android OS to close that dialog?
> Or do we have to respect that Android way of doing it?

I would do that in the onStop() Handler of my app which is called when the user selected an app to start in the dialog (with a flag set to true on the click to go to navi and resettet to false in the onStop() )

I just think that the Android OS would not like messing with its dialogs, or is there a CLEAN way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, after the selection the dialog won't close itself and after returning to the app sometimes the user has to press the back button up to 4x to close that dialog.

This is most likely a problem with your firmware, either due to bugs from the device manufacturer or bugs in some modded firmware that you have installed upon your device.

> So is there any way to get the Android OS to close that dialog?

Android automatically closes the dialog.

Comment: Thanks for supporting, thats about what I thought but now I'm shure :)